# Why does scaling of controls differ between PC's?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, panel, delphi-xe

I try to give the user a 'clean and simple' interface by hiding some elements. Only a small arrow denotes that he can expand some part of the main menu bar. When all is closed it looks like this:

[image]

When you open all it looks like this:

[image]

Each arrow is a SpeedButton thats sits on the left side of a panel. By clicking on the button the Width is toggled between the width of the Speedbutton (closed) and the width of the panel at design time (open). The width of the panel at designtime is stored as a constant. The procedure show_hide_controls handles this:

```
procedure TCompose_Main.show_hide_controls (key: string; Button: TSpeedButton; Panel: TPanel; width: Int32);
begin
   if GPA.iKey [key] = 1
      then Panel.Width := width         // show panel, set panel to design width
      else Panel.Width := Button.Width; // hide panel, set with to button width
   Button.Glyph.Assign (nil);
   Images_Left_Right.GetBitmap (GPA.iKey [key], Button.Glyph);
end; // show_hide_controls //
```

This routine is called as follows:

```
show_hide_controls ('Show Play Controls', // index to panel to show/hide
                    Enlarge_Play,         // Speedbutton requesting the enlargement/hide
                    Panel_Play,           // Panel to show/hide   
                    cPlayWidth);          // Width of panel when shown
```

Now several users report that part of the panel is hidden, like:

[image]

It seems that the operating system (Windows 7) plays some tricks with scaling. I'm not able to duplicate this error. Does anyone understand what is happening here? And is there a neat way to program against this in a settings independent way?

**Update** As GDF rightly pointed out in his answer it has to do with the scaling of the fonts (control panel > Display). This behaves somewhat weird on my machine. Changing it to 150% has a minor impact while changing it to 125% has a major impact. As you might have guessed I tested the first and not the second scaling. Only when a user reported that scaling back from 125% to 100% I could replicate his error on my machine.

I could not find a relation between fonts and the troubles I have as was suggested by several respendents. My system is still suffering from all the tests I did with Courier (not new), Segoe UI, Tahoma and MS Sans Serif :-D. Maybe indirectly because the controls are probably resized to accomodate the text.

How to handle this? I don't know, I'll start experimenting and will let you know if I find something.

Thanks to you all for your help!

Comment: Ir really seems that the font size is the main factor, because the controls that don't have text associated with them (image buttons on the left, for instance) don't seem to be affected. I would suggest you to use the "Anchors" property of the panels to keep their relative space to the left, so you can at least reduce the visual impact.

Comment: @Jeferson - I tried with different font sizes and could not duplicate the problem. The yellow triangle has no text but disappears.

Comment: +1 and Star, this issue is wide-spread in our Delphi development and needs to be known for anyone who wants to build a truly compatible GUI in Delphi.

Comment: I have experience in the past with button disappearing from our print preview window on client pc. It turns out to be the version of comm ctrl dll (ComCtl32.dll) the client use is the older version. Providing the user with the new one solved the problem.

Comment: This is just my guest that it relates to ComCtl32.dll being used. Maybe asking the dll from your client is worth to try. Who knows maybe certain Service Pack or Hotfix change this dll? Pls refer to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)[/link]

Comment: @Hendra - Thanks for the link. My user and I have the correct version of the ComCtl32.dll. We still have the trouble when scaling is different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your problem is what I believe, you just stated the answer. Windows 7 plays with scaling certain fonts. When you install Win7 on a PC it checks the size of your monitor and makes the "default" scale setting either 100% or 125% depending on your monitor size. The problem is that at this same time it installs font files onto the computer. It uses a different font file for the different "default" for some of the fonts.

My guess is your app is using MS Sans Serif... this is one of the fonts that gets different font file installs depending on what scale Win7 is using as the (default).

To verify this have your users tell you want scale is set as the default, you can view this by right clicking the desktop and selecting "personalize" then "Display" at the bottom left.

The following link shows you how to change the in-use-font file back to the original
http://www.rlvision.com/misc/windows_7_font_bug.asp

However, I would make an attempt to get off of this font and update the layout elements to work as desired on Win7 as well as past OSes

This is what I think you are dealing with given the limited amount of information you have provided...

**Update**
Since you reminded me when you mentioned the different looks between 125% v 150%. I just wanted to make sure you were aware that the two different MS Sans Serif files looks better at different scales. One of the font files looks great at 100% and 150% but horrible at 125%. The other font file looks great at 125%, but horrible at 100 and 150%.

I don't quite remember which font file is which, but I know the 2 culprits are
1) SSERIFF.FON 
2) SSERIFE.FON

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try this and come back to you.

Comment: GDF: What default font should be used?

Comment: @WarrenP: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe UI, whatever, any True Type vector font (that can scale without "steps"). Even better: always use the OS default font (which hasn't been MS Sans Serif since... oh,  I can't remember, Win 3.1?)

Comment: @WarrenP The problem font that us Delphi people tend to hit, at least the one I did, is with MS Sans Serif. Windows uses 2 different font files depending on the default windows system scale. Both files are installed on the system, but only one is setup to be used. Follow the link I included in my answer for more details.

Comment: We had some customer-pushback  at one place I worked when we tried to abandon MS Sans Serif because all the true-type fonts looked SO HORRIBLE when accessed via Terminal Server sessions.  MS Sans Serif is a classic non-hinted non-scaled fixed-size font, and looks good in low-bandwidth remote desktop situations, whereas the rest looked like garbage.  Sigh.

Comment: @GDF - Thanks for your answer! It pointed me in the right direction. I explain it in more detail in the updated question