# Form Scaled property set to False, but controls still scaling

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to stop a Delphi 7 application from scaling when the computer has its fonts set to 125% on Windows 7.

I have gone through all the forms and set the scaled property to False on them all, which solves the problem on most of the forms, but there are a few that have dynamically created controls on them, where the control is still being scaled, so I have a mix of some scaled and some not scaled controls on the same form.

Any suggestions why these controls are still being scaled?

As an example, we have a groupbox control on the form. During the form create, another control is dynamically created with the groupbox as its parent. It is this control which is still being scaled. The groupbox appears as it should (ie not scaled).

Comment: So is the issue only with dynamically created controls?

Comment: So far, it appears that way. It isn't all of them, the standard Delphi controls that are dynamically created seem ok. It seems to be the ones that have been written in-house at some point that have problems. I don't know if there is something that needs to be done as part of the Create to make them scale?

Comment: Which type of control is scaled. What do you mean by scaled? If you are creating it dynamically, aren't you setting its dimensions?

Comment: Been playing around with the code, and i managed to get the controls to scale if I removed code in the onCreate which sets up defaults for the ParentFont, Font.Size properties.

Comment: Can this be the famous MSSansSerif problem? MSSansSerif does not work well under Win7, Win7 installs 2 different versions of the font and changes which file it's using depending on your monitor size and zoom. The easiest fix is to switch fonts. Here is my full explanation of the issue on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840674/why-does-scaling-of-controls-differ-between-pcs/10840813#10840813

Comment: Could well be, as it is the font we use throughout the application. Although I thought i had it cracked with the parentfont, font.size properties, I'm still finding some instances of labels not being scaled, but we aren't changing the parentfont or size properties anywhere on those controls. Sadly changing the font throughout the app is likely to be rejected, even though I personally think it would freshen up the app a little :)

Comment: @nehpets You can start by verifying if this is the issue. When you are scaling windows from 100%->125%->150% you can check which of this windows scale values is set as default. Then swap out the font file it uses by updating the registry entries and checking how the scaling changed. More info on the link I provided. If you are at least able to isolate the issue to the "font file Win7 default scale" problem, at least you have a starting point.